# Jquery control appended and repeating elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html element ("trip") that has two dependent select. Jquery is used to determine the selection values for the second selection field (choice2)depending on the value selected for the first election field (choice1).

At the same time, I am also using jquery to duplicate "trip" as a repeating element through the append function. Because all of the elements have the same id, the selection values are the same for all repeating "trip".  1) How do we assign unique id for each appended element (e.g. trip1, trip2) 2) how do you make the jquery make independent calls to get different results with in "trip" element? (e.g. $("trip1"), $("trip2")

Html:

```
<form>
   <div id="trip">
       <select id="choice1" value="Z">
           <option>Option 1</option>
           <option>Option 2</option>
       </select>
       <select id="choice2">
            ...dependent on result of first select...
       </select>
   </div>
 </form>
```

jQuery:

I use the following code to append the same html elements to the page:

```
var maxAppend = 0;
$("#add").click(function() {
   if (maxAppend >= 4) return;

   var additional = $('#trip').html();
   $("#nexttrip").append(additional);
   maxAppend++;
});
```

This is used to determine selection option for the second select based on what was chosen for the frist select.

```
$("#choice1").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Z') {
      $("select#choice2").html("<option>Select a value</option>");
      $("select#choice2").attr('disabled', true);
    }
   else {
     ...determine values for choice2...
   }
```

Comment: Don't use multiple ids, use classes and then eq() and index() to determine which element is handled.

Comment: @frenchie Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Replace ids with classes and make it work with one "trip" element and it'll be obvious then.

Comment: the jquery is triggered when #choice1 is changed. So would I do this? $("#choice1").eq($(this).index()).change(function() {...

Comment: $('.choice1).change(function () {  TheIndexOfThisChoice = $(this).parent().index(); ....

Comment: @frenchie I updated my code to: var current = $(this).index();       $(".choice2").eq(current).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
      $(".choice2").eq(current).attr('disabled', true); However, when I append a new trip, and select a value for choice1, all values in choice2 resets. it seems like parent() always gives -1.

Comment: I think you should put this in a jsFiddle

Comment: @frenchie I have added some sample code in jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/L2bfmo69/).  There are a few problems: 1) when I use eq(), the second select does not reset when the new html is appended. 2) the index for state, skips from 0 to 1 to 5. So I don't understand how the append is assigning index number.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, creating dynamic ids can become a hassle. Instead, assign a class to the `select` elements.

```
<div class="trip">
    <select class="choice1" value="Z">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Z</option>
    </select>
    <select class="choice2" value="Z">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This will allow you to traverse your elements without having id conflicts.

So now, when you duplicate the element you will be able to determine the elements index with `.index()`.

```
$("form").on("change", "select", function(){
    var selInd = $(".choice1").index(this);
    if($(this).val() == "Z"){
        $(".choice2").eq(selInd).html("<option>Select a value</option>");
        $(".choice2").eq(selInd).attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

There is no need to append numbers to ids or classes. You simply pair the `select` elements by index. Since they are side-by-side, they will have the same index in accordance with their class. Hence using `choice1` for the first and `choice2` for the second.

Comment: on the original <select>, it finds that choice2 is index -1. Only when I append trip, does it find choice2's index to be 1.

Comment: With the code I provided, I cannot replicate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say it looks like you have a special meaning for each of the trips? If so, i wouldn't dynamically create elements but rather to pre-create all trips as hidden, and then show them according to your logic. If you don't have special treatment for each trip, than the other writers here are right, use class instead of id.

Regarding the dynamic id, you can do this:

```
var maxAppend = 0;
$("#add").click(function() {
   if (maxAppend >= 4) return;

   var additional = $($('#trip').html());
   additional.attr('id', 'trip' + $('[id^=trip]').length)
   $("#nexttrip").append(additional);
   maxAppend++;
});
```